# Android screenshot error: RGBA override BLOB format buffer should have height == width

Tags: android, image, image-formats, pixelformat, image-reader

I am trying to take screenshots of my Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e) using a service.
I am using the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/mtsahakis/a4dca46b80cb8ac2cd100a7a52f65b1d).

In the code linked, `ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);` is used. Note the `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888`. Now, this won't allow me to compile my project and I am greeted with the error: `Error: Must be one of: ImageFormat.UNKNOWN, ImageFormat.RGB_565... etc`.

So I tried changing `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` to `ImageFormat.JPEG` and it compiles. However, my app now crashes with the message:

> RGBA override BLOB format buffer should have height == width

I've tried changing `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` to `0x4`, `0x1`, `ImageFormat.RGB_565` and a few others. Doing so often results in an exception with the message:

> The producer output buffer format 0x1 doesn't match the ImageReader's configured buffer format 0x4.

This is somehow linked with the format described in `onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)`.

I've seen the [following SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673127/android-imagereader-acquirelatestimage-returns-invalid-jpg#27655022), and it seems the correct format is device-specific, but I've tried them all and the error is one of the above.

I'm at a total loss (and I'm a Java/Android newb), so could really use some help.

Comment: Have you found any answer yet? I have the same issue.

Comment: @TeekamSuthar In the end I  performed a `PixelCopy request`. See the documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy and an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103037/596841

Note that I did not build this into a service, although it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try this!

Comment: facing same issue. any luck?

Comment: @UsmanRana check my comment

Comment: @pookie I want to take screenshot even if application is in background. But Pixelcopy accepts a view holder surface.

Answer (score 2):

Create image reader as follows,

```
 ImageReader imageReader =ImageReader.newInstance(width,
            height,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888,
            MAX_IMAGE_COUNT);
```

Then on the image available listener create bitmap as,

```
          try {
                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image != null && mImagesProduced == 0){
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    Buffer imageBuffer = planes[0].getBuffer().rewind();

                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;

                    // create bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height,
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(imageBuffer);

                    saveImage(context, bitmap);
                }
```

Hope it works